# async_read blocked by async_accept? (boost::asio)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Reads are not handled until after another client connects. This is baffling me, it seems straightforward enough. It appears as if the async_accept is blocking the async_read of all the sessions.

Relevant snippets -

```
server::server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, int port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
{
    boost::shared_ptr<session> s(new session(io_service_));
    acceptor_.async_accept(s->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, s,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void server::handle_accept(boost::shared_ptr<session> s, 
    const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    s->start();
    boost::shared_ptr<session> s(new session(io_service_));
    acceptor_.async_accept(s->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, s,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

---

```
void session::start()
{   
    boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_,buffer_,' ',
        boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this, 
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void session::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    std::cout << "handling read.";
    boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_,buffer_,' ',
        boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

Am I making some obvious mistake in this basic implementation?

Comment: outside of not checking the `error_code` for errors, and the shadowed parameter in `server::handle_accept()`, I don't see anything obviously wrong in the posted snippet. Is your `io_service` somehow running out of work? Can you post a more complete example?

Comment: Well this is embarrassing and I'm still not sure why, but it appears that the messages sent to std::cout were just not appearing until the next connection. std::cerr displays the messages appropriately. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I guess std::cout is buffered. Append `<< std::endl`.